# SSL Certificates doesn't work

Tags: c#, iis, ssl, localhost

My problem is that I have an application on .net is mvc
The application make "Facturas Electronicas" for the company that I work.
If I run the application on my computer from the visual studio, the application works fine.
But if I publish the app to another server the application doesn't make the "Factura Electronica", but before this erros the application works fine on other servers.
All started when I publish another app with the same code, and needs the same certificates but it is to other product and i need the two applications.

After checking all the code I realize that the problem was the certificate a pfx file,
when the app try to execute this

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificadoDemo, claveCertificadoDemo);
```

the navigator return this

> This webpage is not available

the expiration of the pfx file is until july 2014

Do anyone knows what is going on?

adding this

```
X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet
```

to that line of code i resolved the problem

this is the new line of code

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificadoDemo, claveCertificadoDemo, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

thanks

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? Are you sure that you're using the proper password for the PFX in question and that its location is readable from the account running the app?

Comment: i resolve that adding to the code this

                    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificadoDemo, claveCertificadoDemo, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

Answer (score 1):

Your question cannot be answered without a detailed exception. Either turn off customErrors in the web.config file (in which case, the entire exception will be sent to the browser) or catch errors in Global.asax Application_Error event handler and log the errors to a file somehow (using System.Diagnostics preferably). Without more sample code, we can't even know which constructor you're calling because X509Certificate2 has 5 constructors which take two parameters. See http://sscce.org/ on how to ask questions.

Comment: the custom errors are off, the application doesn't send errors just display that message, and that means that there's no internet, but there is internet